# How to edit PATH variable in Mac 10.8.2?

Tags: path, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having a lot of trouble editing my `PATH`. I've seen instructions to add to the front or to the back of `PATH`, but I would actually like to change the order of places in my `PATH`, so I would really just like access to edit it.**

I've been using the terminal so far, because I have no idea how to access `PATH` otherwise.

When I try `ECHO $PATH` I get:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/erensila/.rvm/bin
```

However, I can't seem to find any file where all this information is contained.

For one thing, I don't seem to have a `.profile` in my home directory, or anywhere else.
The only file which seems to contain any PATH related information is my `~/.bash_profile` but this file only seems to handle the adding of Python and RVM related locations to the `PATH`.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand how to edit PATH/where to access it. 
Also, should I be concerned that I don't have a .profile? Is that something I should somehow create?

Thank you!

**The reason I'd like to be able to edit PATH rather than just append paths to the start or end, is because Homebrew reccommends that /usr/local/bin come before /usr/bin in the PATH.

Comment: This would be a better fit for http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Try also checking /etc/paths there are quite a few places where path can be set/edited but this is usually the global source of the path in 10.8 as far as I've seen

Comment: Thank you. I've indeed found some components of my path there. I take it that /etc/paths is a file, right? It's normal that it's not a directory?..